# react-native open modal automatically when state is changed

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am using [react-native-modalbox](https://github.com/maxs15/react-native-modalbox). What I want to do is open modal automatically when state is changed rather than using a button.

Below is my code it works fine with the button. But I want the modal to open when `stateChange` state is changed.

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from 'react-native-button';
import Modal from 'react-native-modalbox';
import {Text, StyleSheet, ScrollView, View, Dimensions, TextInput} from 'react-native';
var screen = Dimensions.get('window');

export default class TestScreen extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isDisabled: false,
      number:''

//I want to open modal when this state is changed

      stateChange:''
    };
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <View style={styles.wrapper}>

// When I press this button it opens a modal  

        <Button onPress={() => this.refs.modal3.open()} style={styles.btn}>Position centered + backdrop + disable</Button>

        <Modal style={[styles.modal, styles.modal3]} position={"center"} ref={"modal3"} isDisabled={this.state.isDisabled}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>Modal centered</Text>
          <Button onPress={() => this.setState({isDisabled: !this.state.isDisabled})} style={styles.btn}>Disable ({this.state.isDisabled ? "true" : "false"})</Button>
        </Modal>

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**Edited**

I want to use react lifecycle method to listen to this update and automatically update it. So I am using `componentDidUpdate`. I want to update `this.state.number` when ever `mobx` store is updated. However, the code below wouldn't work.

```
componentDidUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    this.setState({number:store.requestObject.number},
    console.log(this.state.number), 'state changed')
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use  `isOpen` property of the modal to open it based on the state.
Take one property `isOpen` in your state and change it based on your preconditions, and `isOpen` will open the modal.

```
<Modal isOpen={this.state.isOpen}>content</Modal>
```

Check [this](https://github.com/maxs15/react-native-modalbox/blob/master/Example/index.ios.js#L90)

Comment: thanks very much for the answer, however, I have one issue, I am changing state from another screen so I need to listen for the change and update it but having some issue could you please see my edited question.